# dynamicUpdate=true in Hibernate using annotations not working

Tags: hibernate, annotations

Even after using dynamicUpdate=true(for updating selective columns instead of all columns) in the entity class annotation using org.hibernate.annotations.entity(dynamicUpdate=true), hibernate is trying to update all the fields of the table and since I am having "not null" constraints on few columns, it throws exception. How to resolve this? Please help as soon as possible..

Answer (score 4):

For dynamic update to work you should fetch the object form hibernate first and then change the fields.

```
p = session.get(Person.class,1);
p.setFirstName("Kamal");
```

This will result in a query that will only update the first_name columnn.

The following doesn't work. It will issue an update query with all other columns set to null.

```
p = new Person()
p.setId(1)
p.setFirstName("Kamal")
session.update(p)
```

If you want to update only certain columns you can use the update HQL command.  This is not recommended - as it by passes the cache.  The correct approach is the one outlined above, load the object and then change the fields that need to be changed.

Comment: I am getting the values to be updated from the UI. So i cannot use the session.get() prior to changing the values of the object. Is there any other option for doing selective update? Please Help!!

Comment: How does getting values from UI prevent you from doing a get, you have the id - use it to load the object and then copy the other data from UI onto it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response. I tried by first doing a session.get() and then changing the values. I am able to run the query without any errors but the update statement generated by Hibernate still shows all the fields being updated. But all fields are not updated. I just want to know, why the query is generated so?

Comment: Did you try this with dynamicUpdate=true? By default dynamicUpdate=false so hibernate will update all columns - which usually is not an issue. In case of db locating the row is more expensive - updating few column vs all doesn't add significant overheard.

Comment: Yes i have used the annotation @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true) and i have followed the way u have mentioned above. But still in the query it takes all of the columns instead of the columns that have been modified.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, selectBeforeUpdate = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic update works only when first we fetch value by using session.get(...) In this case suppose we have 10 columns and we want to update 5 columns then first we fetch object by using id then set new value into fetched object and it works fine More we write coding only for 5 columns and if we update one column from that 5 column then by using dynamic update query fire as shown below

Hibernate: update usermaster set name=? where user_id=?

below is my code and here i chenged only name from front end

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();
Usermaster obj = (Usermaster) session.get(Usermaster.class,
        usermaster.getUserId());
obj.setUsername(usermaster.getUsername());
obj.setName(usermaster.getName());
obj.setContact(usermaster.getContact());
obj.setEmail(usermaster.getEmail());
obj.setUserStatus(usermaster.getUserStatus());
obj.setUserType(usermaster.getUserType());
session.update(obj);
```